# Emacs: how to enable hanging indent in auto-fill-mode?

Tags: emacs, indentation

In auto-fill-mode, I want emacs to auto-fill paragraph with hanging indentation, like this:

```
This is an example of hanging indented
    paragraph. The first line is indented
    less than the following lines in a
    paragraph.

Another paragraph starts from here, and
    lines are broken.
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the effect you want automatically by putting the following lines into you .emacs file:

```lisp
(setq adaptive-fill-function '(lambda () "    "))
```

The string at the end of the line is the width of the hanging indent.

Answer (score 3):

Simply indent the second line manually. Then when you hit <kbd>M-q</kbd> the whole paragraph will be indented the way you want.

Comment: uh.. that's inconvenient :(, no way to automatically do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this interactively using `M-x set-fill-prefix`, bound by default to `C-x .` (that's a period, or full-stop, after the C-x).

Manually, *only once*, indent the second line of a single paragraph, and while your cursor (point) is at that position, press `C-x .`. All auto-fills from now on will indent anything past the first line accordingly.

In order to reset the behavior, move your cursor the beginning of a line and invoke `C-x .` again.

As a bonus, you aren't restricted to having this fill prefix be limited to spaces. For example you could include comment symbols or vertical lines or your $PS1.

You may also be interested in `M-x auto-fill-mode` which toggles *automatic* line-wrapping and justification. That will save you from having to manually selecting regions and typing `M-q`.

If you really want to get fancy, you can write your own custom function for this, and set variable `normal-auto-fill-function` to point to your function.